# Non orthogonal to Orthogonal coordinates system conversion in Python

Tags: python, computational-geometry, coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation

I have a vector in a non-orthogonal coordinate system spanned by axes a,b,c and their Euler angles alpha(between b&c),beta(between c&a),gamma(between a&b). I want to convert this vector to an orthogonal coordinate system spanned by x,y,z. I assume that axes a and x coincide while conversion.
I can do it mathematically by solving equations for coordinates, but I was wondering if there exists any library in Python to do it efficiently.
(I found a library  - transforms3d. But I couldn't understand its documentation well.)

Answer (score 0):

The best coordinate system transformations function I've knowen in python is this one: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/code/transformations.py.html

Take a look at the functions: euler_matrix and euler_from_matrix.
It comes with a self explained comments in the code.

Other libraries that might be relevant is:

1. Shapely - http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html
2. Blender - https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_62_0/mathutils.html